# AlarmManager set is not firing broadcast

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to schedule notifications using the AlarmManager but for whatever reason, the onReceive method on my receiver isn't firing.

Here's how I'm scheduling the alarm

```
        val intent = Intent(this, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)

        val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5)
        
        val amanager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        amanager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
```

and here's the onReceive method

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

I tried manually sending a broadcast to see if it works and there's no problem there so the issue shouldn't be related to the manifest.

I'm running this on MIUI12 android 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no issue with your logic if your problem still prevails, try the following as a workaround

```
val intent = Intent(this, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)

//        val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
//        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5)
        
        val triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5_000 // five seconds from now


        val amanager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
     //   amanager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
        AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                    amanager,
                    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    triggerTime,
                    pendingIntent
                )
```

Comment: glad it worked, check out the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/AlarmManagerCompat) for more info on `AlarmManagerCompat`